# imagemagic: combine two grid images

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I have two big images with identical dimensions.
Each image composed on the 4x6 elements splited in the form of grid (table) with identical border. Here is the both inputs in resized format (actual resolution is 7384x2872)
[image]

[image]

Is it possible to use any utilities of Image Magic or other software working on Mac, to take any number of the central grids (surrounded by a perimeter by other elements) from the first image and insert it to the same central position of the image 2 (thus making a substitution of selected grids )?

Comment: It would be better if you posted the two images. Then we can understand your issue better and try to give you a solution.

Comment: it is actually two relatively big images with the identical dimensions, I am going to share them in my first topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call your first image `a.jpg` and the second `b.jpg` and assume we want to copy the right-most cell from the second row of the first into the second.

Now that cell is 112x64 and at offset +577+69 from the top-left corner, so we want to:

- load the first image
- crop out the cell
- load the second image
- put the second image at the bottom
- flatten the cropped part of the first image onto the second

That looks like this:

```
magick a.jpg -crop 112x64+577+69 b.jpg +swap -flatten result.jpg
```

I have made an animation of the `a.jpg`, `b.jpg` and the result here:

[image]

---

If you dislike doing things in the *"wrong"* order, you can do exactly the same thing by loading `b.jpg` first, then in some bracketed  *"aside-processing"* loading and cropping just `a.jpg` before flattening:

```
magick b.jpg \( a.jpg -crop 112x64+577+69 \) -flatten result.jpg
```

Comment: IMHO it is IM ver 7

Comment: @Adam I am not sure what your comment means, but the code is for **ImageMagick** version 7. Change `magick` to `convert` and it will work for v6.